# magento database 2.4.6

Tags: magento2.4.6

I have a problem when saving a product in the database, it is taking a long time to do the process, specifically in $product->save();

in my database I have a maximum of 4800 products.

the characteristics of my server are:

8 GB RAM, 160 GB SSD Disk, 5 TB Transfer, 4 Core Processor

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: I was already able to solve the problem, it was more of a problem with the server and the database indexes, the problem is that there were many index executions when saving a single product, thank youWilson

Comment: If you would like suggestions to improve speed of query completion, please Additional DB information requested.  Glad you got reindex settled down.